# Error while using string.Format for strings with newline chars

Tags: c#, string.format

Getting error while using string.Format

errorMessage is "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@title='Client nc.']"}"

code:

````
errorMessage = (exceptions.CurrentDotNetExceptionMessage.ToString() + "\n" + exceptions.CurrentDotNetInnerException.ToString().Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).FirstOrDefault()) ?? string.Empty;


 defectDetails = string.Format($"Issue: {actualResult} \n\n" +
                $"Steps To Reproduce: \n {stepsToReproduce} \n\n" +
                $"Failed Step: \n {failedStep} \n" +
                $"Failed Element: \n {failedElement} \n" +
                $"Test Data: \n {testData} \n\n" +
                $"Actual Result: \n {actualResult} \n" +
                $"Expected Result: \n {expectedResult} \n" +
                $"Error Message: \n {errorMessage.ToString()} \n\n" +
                $"Browser: {browser} \n" +
                $"Enviornment: {environment}\n\n" +
                $"Stack Trace: {stackTrace}" +
                $"\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
                );``` 
Error Line:   
```string.Format($"Error Message: \n {errorMessage} \n");```

Error: string.FormatException
````

Comment: I'm confused why you're putting an interpolated string inside a call to string.Format. Use one or the other (remove string.format would be my choice)

Comment: share your code to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: Used string.Format along with interpolation. Worked when removed string.Format

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the first line when assigning errorMessage .In the end of the assigned string you put {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@title='Apple nc.']"}";
when you want to use " in your string you must put a \ before, otherwise it's assumed as the end of the string.